# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to 'NSIndexPath'

Tags: swift

I got this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to 'NSIndexPath'

Below is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToProfile2", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ToProfile2" {
        let index = sender as! NSIndexPath
        print(index)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've recreated situation like in snapshot and it just works. Tested with Xcode 11.2/iOS 13.2. I think the error not in this place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, however `indexPath` is not the sender, the cell you are selecting should be. Try:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToProfile2", sender: self)
}
```

And if you want to identify the `indexPath` for the cell you just selected, below would give you that:

```
tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs if the origin of segue is the table view cell.

There are two options:

1. Delete `didSelect`, cast the `sender` parameter to `UITableViewCell` and call `tableview.indexPath(for:` to get the index path.
2. In Interface Builder delete the segue and recreate it starting from the controller

Comment: I had same issue. You're point(2) helped not only fix the issue but also understand how "sender" works in SWIFT. Thank you